# Does MD5 create same hash code for two same binaries even if add few lines code of 2nd one?

Tags: hash, md5

I have created small automated antivirus tool it works with MD5 hash code.it takes the hash of binary then compare with existing signatures in database.

Suppose if malware author just change/add few lines of  code of malware then it will generate same hash key?or different one? Does it generate same hash key even if enhance/alter the code?

Comment: I wonder what you think a hash is.

Comment: MD5 hashes are old news for such uses.

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of checksums is that a small change is supposed to result in a large change to the hash.

That being said, checksum collisions are a fact of life and clever people can make changes to code very carefully, such that the checksum remains the same. I'd say that in general this is a low risk, though, because doing this would take serious effort.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, any change in the source binary would generate a different hash. However, the MD5 algorithm is not collision resistant. It is possible (though somewhat unlikely) that 2 different binaries generate the same hash.

Comment: _"Theoretically, any change in the source binary should generate a different hash"_ That is not true. _Any_ hash algorithm has collisions.

Answer (score 2):

That is generally true for Hash function, however MD5 is not considered secure anymore as you can read [Here](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/)

> In March 2005, Xiaoyun Wang and Hongbo Yu of Shandong University in
>   China published an article in which they describe an algorithm that
>   can find two different sequences of 128 bytes with the same MD5 hash.

It is also not secure specifically for ps files [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20071226014140/http://www.cits.rub.de/MD5Collisions/).